# Flutter How to model firebase user fields

Tags: firebase, flutter

Hello everyone I'am trying to model firebase user fields but it returns me an error.

My `model`:

```
factory UserModel.fromDatabase(DocumentSnapshot snapshot, Map docData) {
    return UserModel(
      uid: snapshot.id,
      name: docData['name'],
      email: docData['email'],
      bildirim: docData['bildirim'],
      kullaniciAdi: docData['kullaniciAdi'],
      pphoto: docData['pphoto'],
      sehir: docData['sehir'],
    );
}
```

Function `getUserData`:

```
Future<UserModel> getUserData(String uid) async {
    try {
      var _doc = await _firestore.collection("users").doc(uid).get();
      Map? _docData = _doc.data();
      return UserModel.fromDatabase(_doc, _docData!);
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      Get.snackbar("ERROR", e.code);
      rethrow;
    }
}
```

I get `uid` from Firebase current user uid.

Also, I am using GetX and I am calling `getUserData` method like this:

```
_initialScreen(User? user) async {
    if (user == null) {
      Get.offAllNamed('/LoginView');
    } else {
      Get.offAllNamed('/RootView');
      userModel = await _firebaseServices.getUserData(auth.currentUser!.uid);
    }
}
```

And here is error:

> W/DynamiteModule(24534): Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
> I/DynamiteModule(24534): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
> W/ProviderInstaller(24534): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
> E/flutter (24534): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
> E/flutter (24534): #0      FirebaseServices.getUserData
> package:bookingappbeta/…/firebase/fb_service.dart:34
> E/flutter (24534): 
> E/flutter (24534): #1      HomeController._initialScreen
> package:bookingappbeta/…/controllers/home_controller.dart:38
> E/flutter (24534): 
> E/flutter (24534):

Comment: Can you show where you're calling the **getUserData** method? Are you calling it from a controller of some sort? Using a state management strategy? I'd like to see more of the code if you don't mind

Comment: I added it inside question.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is already in your StackTrace:

```
E/flutter (24534): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
E/flutter (24534): #0      FirebaseServices.getUserData
package:bookingappbeta/…/firebase/fb_service.dart:34
E/flutter (24534): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (24534): #1      HomeController._initialScreen
```

So within `FirebaseServices.getUserData` you have a `Null check operator` (the `!`) on a null value.
The only `!` you use in this function is the one in

```
return UserModel.fromDatabase(_doc, _docData!);
```

Which means the `data()` method returned null. What again means, that there is no entry in your `users` collection for this id.

So you should do two things:

1. check where the field should have been created. Probably directly after the sign in. Maybe there is something wrong.
2. within your `getUserData` method you should check if the snapshot already exists, instead of using `!`. You could also think about creating the missing field at that point if it doesn't exist. I am thinking about sth. like:

```
Future<UserModel> getUserData(String uid) async {
    try {
      var _doc = await _firestore.collection("users").doc(uid).get();
    
      if (!_doc.exists()) {
         _doc = _createUserDoc(uid);
      }
    
      Map? _docData = _doc.data();
      return UserModel.fromDatabase(_doc, _docData!);
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      Get.snackbar("ERROR", e.code);
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

Comment: but there is an existing field already and my code was working until last update.

Comment: Hm. Okay. Quick question: Why are you passing `auth.currentUser!.uid` to your `getUserData` method instead of `user.uid` ?

Comment: Because I have to query with current user uid from Firebase. Firebase doc's name is user uid.

Comment: Yes, sure. But `user.uid` would give you the same. Is it already solved? Otherwise for helping I would need a bit more context. I.e. Logo-Outputs of the user uid, Firestore Screenshot that it is really existing

Comment: Okey then, I still don't handle with how to model Firebase fields. It returns me an error. Actually, I tried to query for user field but still getting null but there is a field in firebase.

Comment: Can you provide the logoutput and the screenshot?

Comment: I added a new answer about error sir.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242540/discussion-between-niklaslehnfeld-and-tolga-yilmaz).